# How to install ROS fuerte on ubuntu 11.10 64 bits?

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I apt-get it shows:

```
sam@robot:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full
[sudo] password for sam: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-fuerte-desktop-full : Depends: ros-fuerte-nodelet-core (= 1.6.5-s1347168835~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1348603799~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1347124102~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-filters (= 1.6.0-s1347133504~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1350948390~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo (= 1.6.16-s1347172830~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization (= 1.8.14-s1350944568~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-vision-opencv (= 1.8.8-s1349900876~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-perception-pcl (= 1.2.3-s1347170256~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.3-s1347133731~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model-visualization (= 0.1.2-s1347128386~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-common-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1348603925~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-image-pipeline (= 1.8.5-s1349902794~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-bfl (= 0.1.0-s1347124244~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-diagnostics-monitors (= 1.4.3-s1347133511~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-common-rosdeps (= 1.2.0-s1347122840~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-visualization (= 0.1.1-s1347141454~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-image-common (= 1.8.0-s1347133482~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-bond-core (= 1.6.3-s1347128144~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-python-qt-binding (= 0.1.9-s1348595482~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-common (= 1.8.4-s1347128602~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-physics-ode (= 1.8.0-s1347122907~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-driver-common (= 1.4.0-s1347168681~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-executive-smach (= 1.2.0-s1347133680~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-stage (= 1.6.6-s1347133988~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-dynamic-reconfigure (= 1.4.2-s1347168414~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.2-s1349902769~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-xacro (= 1.6.1-s1347128571~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model (= 1.8.1-s1347133837~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-bullet (= 2.79-s1347124289~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-pluginlib (= 1.8.0-s1347128156~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry (= 1.8.2-s1347128281~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials (= 0.6.3-s1350946267~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-executive-smach-visualization (= 1.0.2-s1347141801~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline (= 1.4.5-s1350943746~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1347122771~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-common (= 1.8.0-s1347133548~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-diagnostics (= 1.6.4-s1347133484~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-fuerte-navigation (= 1.8.3-s1350945002~precise) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
sam@robot:~$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48437/how-to-install-ros-fuerte-on-ubuntu-11.10-64-bits?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to install Precise packages (Ubuntu 12.04) instead of Oneiric packages. Fix `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` (rename precise by oneiric) and don't forget to `sudo apt-get update` before you try to install again.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0